# Why do these errors appear? c# - hangman game

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to coding (especially c#) - this is an assignment for a programming fundamentals class - I'm not looking for the answer - I'm looking for someone to explain why I get these two 'error's for a boolean method I'm supposed to create to check if the user's guess for a letter or the full word in a game of hangman.
The errors I get are - 'Unreachable Code detected - for the idx++ part - which doesn't make sense as I've used it in other separate methods..
And Program.CheckGuess(char[], char[], char[], string: not all code paths return a value.

I know I'm not fully finished the aspect. It's probably staring at me in the face - just looking for some guidance. Thanks.

```
static bool CheckGuess(char[] secrets, char[] mask, char[] letters, string guess)
{ 
    int misses = 0; bool condition = false;

    for (int idx = 0; idx < secret.Length; idx++)
    {
        guess.ToCharArray();
        if (mask[idx] == guess[idx])
        {
            //reveal character or word
            condition = true;
        } 
        else
        {
            misses = misses + 1;
            condition = false;
        }
        return condition;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand that a `return` statement, when executed, makes the control jump out of the method and back to the caller.

In your code, your `return` is statement is placed inside the for loop. When an iteration of the for loop is executed, the control jumps out of the method immediately and goes back to the caller of the method.

As you know, the last part in a for loop header (`idx++`) is executed when an iteration has finished executing. However, in your case, an iteration will never finish because it just jumps back to the caller when control reaches `return`. This is why the first error occurred.

You should also understand that every method which doesn't have `void` as the return type needs to `return` no matter what.

So what if the for loop's condition (the middle part) is never `true`? The for loop will never be executed, right? If the for loop isn't executed, then what should the method return?

The error says that not all code path returns a value because the method would not return if the for loop isn't executed.

To fix this, you just need to move the `return` statement out of the for loop:

```
static bool CheckGuess(char[] secrets, char[] mask, char[] letters, string guess)
{ 
    int misses = 0; bool condition = false;

    for (int idx = 0; idx < secret.Length; idx++)
    {
        guess.ToCharArray();
        if (mask[idx] == guess[idx])
        {
            //reveal character or word
            condition = true;
        } 
        else
        {
            misses = misses + 1;
            condition = false;
        }
    }
    return condition;
 }
```

Comment: It's always something so small with me - argh - but thank you for the explanation. I did know that - but for some ridiculous reason I thought I had the return statement already outside the for loop... yeah, time for a break. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a `return` statement.

When this `return` inside your `for` loop is reached, the program jumps out of the loop and thus makes you `i++` unreachable.

Comment: Damn it!!! It's always something so little! Gah! Thanks - that fixed both issues... Seriously, thanks. It's now time for a very long break.